# Web application deploy on web server

Tags: asp.net, web-config

While I am trying to deploy my web application to the web server it throws following error.

> It is an error to use a section registered as allowDefinition='MachineToApplication' beyond application level.  This error can be caused by a virtual directory not being configured as an application in IIS.

You can see the site by clicking [here](http://www.marketsyztems.com/easybooknet/Default.aspx).

I had developed this web application in framework 4.0, with VS2012.

I check this entire site in my local machine IIS 7.

I am afraid from this problem.

Comment: Never show your web.config content to the end client, change the debug flag to false.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Delete the `obj` folder in your solution folder, and you should be able to publish again.

Comment: There is no **Obj** folder.

Comment: Not on your webserver, in the projectfolder on your development machine

Comment: Exactly same place, I don't have any **Obj** folder, on my development machine...

Comment: Ok, then I misread your question. I thought the error occurred while deploying your website. Is your virtual directory configures as application, as stated in the error message?

Comment: I don't know about it, basically I have just FTP access so can't say anything about it...

Comment: I suggest you ask the hostingprovider to create an application for that directory in IIS then